# Fluidmaster float sticks on brand new Champion toilet

Tags: toilet

My Fluidmaster float sticks on brand new Champion toilet. Seems to hang up on every third flush. Turns out there was an imperfection in the tube with a bit of plastic flash sticking out that was catching the float. I used a nail file to grind off the projection and now all is well. Not sure why Fluidmaster cannot make smooth tubing.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Edit your question into an actual question, then put what you found as an answer and accept it as the answer. This is valuable info for future folks who might encounter the same problem.

Comment: "*Not sure why Fluidmaster cannot make smooth tubing*".  Do you realize you said that out loud on the internet?  If you really want to know then  **You will have to ask Fluidmaster**.

Comment: Well done solving your problem, and thank you for sharing it.  You can learn more how SE works by reading the [tour] but to get closure on this, try posting an answer of your own.  Ideally the answer would have photos showing exactly what the cause was and how you fixed it.